# Load a complete DB from CSV using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have about 20 csv files each of them representing one DB table. I tried to use Spring Batch as example to load one table and it was fine. One single job, with one single step composed by: a reader, a processor and a writer. Anyway each bean in the definition is casted to the Entity representing the table. So using this approach, I think it is not feasible to load 20 tables. Is there a way to have a generic reader (with associated mapper), processor and writer (with the corresponding list of columns)? Or is there a smarter way to load such files in the database? Thanks for the helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch - FlatFileItemReader for different delimited files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966644/spring-batch-flatfileitemreader-for-different-delimited-files)

Comment: Not really, I would like to make the reader and the writer generic, not depending of the Entity class name

Comment: ok let's suppose you have the generic reader with its associated generic mapper, how will you pass which columns to read and to which entity they should be mapped?